# How to get the Captured Image's Creation Dates in Android

Tags: android

Iam developing one android Application, in which iam using the Camera Functionality.
Is there any way to get the  Captured Images's Creation Dates in Android?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Through the Exif interface, if the camera write it. take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html#TAG_DATETIME)

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(pathToTheImage);
String datetime =  exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and i will look into  Exif interface

Comment: Hi, Blackbelt.  Iam unable to get the selected image path from gallery.Can you tell me how to get the selected image path from SD card?

Comment: you should show your code. Otherwise is impossible give you help

Comment: Iam using the following code to show the selected image from Gallery. protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {   if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && null != data) try {    if (bitmap != null) {      bitmap.recycle();    } String date;InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(  data.getData()); bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream); stream.close();ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_capture);  imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Comment: did you figured it out ?

Comment: in my code, what is the selected image path to pass to the ExifInterface class?

Comment: are you using the camera intent (ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) ?

Comment: i want to browse the image from gallery

Answer (score 1):

Use the following method to get image's captured date

```
private String getPhotoCapturedDate(String filePath){

        //String capturedDate = null;
        try {
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);
            if(exif != null){

                return exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create one string variable

call simple date format object in that string variable

new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
                .format(new Date());

now pass this string into image path ...